# Asynchronous ajax request locking browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, browser, locking

This is a simple snippet of code to launch an **aynchronous** ajax request. 
The processing time of the request is **deliberately long** (10 seconds or more).

Why **browser prevent my users to click** on a href link during the process of the async request ? 
(tried with Firefox and Chrome)

The **async request is normally called** and the 'Ready' message is immediately displayed in console.

*Snippet :*

```
new Ajax.Request('index.php', {
    method: 'post',
    asynchronous: true,
    parameters: { 'sleep': 10 },
    onSuccess:  function(transport) { console.log('Success'); },
    onFailure: function() { console.log('Error'); }
});

console.log('Ready');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is the cause of the problem here. When you do session_start() the PHP locks the session file so there’s no concurrent writing to this file and gives the running script full access to the session variables ( reading and writing ).

So you need to call session_write_close() as soon as possible.