# How to fix jQuery AJAX call preventing user from leaving page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have page that has two main queries - an item and similar items.

The item is fetched as normal but the similar items are loaded as a separate jQuery ajax call which automatically triggers as the page loads. The similar items are then appended to the page. The second query is separated because it can occasionally be slow and affect user experience.

```
$.post(url, function(output) {
  if (output) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(output);
    if (data.success) {
      $("div").html(data.html);
    }
  }
});
```

I'm now noticing that the ajax query holds up the page even when trying to navigate away. The browser won't allow a user to leave the page until the ajax query returns something - either similar items or no results.

I haven't dealt with this scenario before. Is there a way to structure this JQuery ajax call in a way that wouldn't force the user to wait for it to complete? Addressing the speed of the server-side response is not an option at the moment.

**UPDATE/ANSWER:**

Posted below as an answer.

Comment: please post more code

Comment: @messerbill What code exactly would be useful? That's all the jQuery does.

Comment: Not sure how that call would do it since it is asynchronous unless you have code somewhere that makes all the Ajax calls sync.

Comment: @Tom ... due to my poor English I am not sure if your question is to `abort` the ajax or `still on the same page until ajax finish` ? Mi answer above is about abort

Comment: @epascarello I don't understand it either. This jQuery is inlined and there is nothing else tied to it.

Comment: @MTK ... I simply want a href click of a normal link on the page to override and allow the user to navigate away at any point, even if the ajax call hasn't returned something.

Comment: Is your JSON huge that it is trying to parse?

Comment: @epascarello Not huge, just some HTML. It's the database query that holds it up on server-side as it's quite complex.

Comment: @Tom `beforeunload` not working for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer here:

[Asynchronous ajax request locking browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712449/asynchronous-ajax-request-locking-browser)

PHP on the server is locking the session and it can be unlocked using php `session_write_close()` in the server-side code called by the ajax. Although nothing has been returned by the ajax call, clicking on a link needs the session for the next page, which is still hanging from processing the ajax call.

Comment: Suggest closing this as duplicate, as - well - it's duplicate, clearly....

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe looks to be *"the browser is locked while the request is active"*.
You possibly have something like the code below somewhere:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
  // And other parameters...
})
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

So... The only way to revert that is to find that code chunk and change it... **OR** to just redefine the `async` parameter again, just before the `$.post()` executes:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not have async set to false, and I tried using ajaxSetup() to redeclare it but it doesn't do anything. I've tried loading nothing except vanilla jQuery 3.2.1 and my ajax call inside a document.ready() and it hangs the same way. I can sleep the server response for 10 seconds and the user will be locked for 10 seconds.

Comment: Can you share the live link where that occurs?

Comment: @Loyus Patrice Bessette  Unfortunately not, it's on my development machine and quite deep inside the app. I've now also tried with three different versions of jQuery - same result.

Comment: I've found it! It's because PHP, unbelievable. Need to call PHP session_write_close() to release the session. Will add answer above.